# How do I extract data from a returned JSON object and put each value into a new column in a CSV?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I'm hitting an API endpoint and incrementing over a range of unique IDs to gather data. Think something like google.com/api/x where x is the ID that I'm incrementing.

All of this is currently working fine, but the data is returned in JSON format. What I'd like to be able to do is extract each key:value pair of this object into a new column. So instead of being one cell filled with the entire JSON object, the object would be extracted to have each value in its own cell with the key as the header, if that makes sense.

I have my code below. Currently, as I mentioned above, it's just dumping the entire JSON object into a single cell.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

booking_id = x

HEADERS = {'user-agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5)'
                          'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                          'Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'),
                          'referer': 'https://book.nightsbridge.com/'}

def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data
    
    else:
        print(response.text)
        print(response.status_code)

df = pd.DataFrame([])

for i in range(y):
    base_url = "URL"   
    booking_url = base_url + str(booking_id)
    data = get_data(booking_url)
    df.to_csv('filename1.csv')
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
    
    booking_id +=1

df.to_excel('filename2.xlsx')
```

Any advice on how best to achive this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `What I'd like to be able to do is extract each key:value pair of this object into a new column. ` - Can you add some data sample (json format) and expected ouput?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the reply! Some JSON formatted data below and also the expected output.

`[{
  "data": {
    "content": {
      "id": "Pink",
      "active": "Aquamarine",
      "name": "Turquoise"
    },
    "contact": {
      "phone": "Maroon",
      "email": "Green"
    }
  },
  "address": {
    "line1": "Pink",
    "line2": "Fuscia",
    "city": "Purple",
    "postalcode": "Yellow",
    "country": "Maroon"
  }
}]`

Expected output would ID, Active, Name, Phone, Email, Line1, Line2, City, Postalcode, Country as column headers with value as the corresponding data.

Comment: Use `pd.json_normalize(json)`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, that worked great! 

Do you have any idea how I could normalize a sub-array within that JSON data (I hope that terminology is correct)? Right now, the output is values in cells but occasionally there is a nested array that is not normalized into its own cells (If that makes sense). 

I've tried messing around with Lambda and max_level and record_path with normalize but haven't had much success...